# FFMPEG - extract two consecutive frames

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I need to use FFMPEG to randomly select time (e.g. 0:10) and save two consecutive frames as PNG.

**HOW TO SAVE FRAME TO PNG:**

```
ffmpeg.exe -ss 0:10 -y -i test.avi -vcodec png -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo test.png
```

**HOW TO EXTRACT INFO ABOUT THE VIDEO FILE:**

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=duration,avg_frame_rate -of default=nw=1:nk=0 test.avi
```

Output:

```
avg_frame_rate=120/1
duration=59.808333
```

**QUESTION**

How to determine next frame? Frame rate 120/1 means 120 frames per second?

**EDIT**

Possible solution - am I correct that extracting the frames at times +(1/120 = 0.00833333) would solve my problem?:

```
-ss 0:10
-ss 0:10.00833333
```

Does it guarantee exactly the next frame? Is there any other approach?

Answer (score 0):

Use the image sequence muxer

```
ffmpeg -ss 0:10 -y -i test.avi -vframes 2 -vsync 0 -an -f image2 test%d.png
```

This will output test1.png and test2.png, the frames being consecutive.